# FOSUserBundle with two authentication methods

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a `Symfony 2.8` project in which I am using `FOSUserBundle`. The `FOSUser` authentication method uses the `fos_user` table to identify and validate credentials and the key that is encrypted using `sha512`.

Is it possible to modify or extend some classes so that in case it does not find the user in the table `fos_user`, look for it in the user table in which the key is encrypted using `md5`?

Updating according to the sundown of madshvero:

**I have created a user class:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Security\User;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;

class WebserviceUser implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface
{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $salt;
    private $roles;

    public function __construct($username, $password, $salt, array $roles)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->salt = $salt;
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof WebserviceUser) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->salt !== $user->getSalt()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->username !== $user->getUsername()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**I have also created the user provider:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Security\User;

use AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;

class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        // make a call to your webservice here
        $userData = true;
        // pretend it returns an array on success, false if there is no user

        if ($userData) {
            $username = 'prueba';
            $password = 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e'; // md5('123456')
            $salt = '';`enter code here`
            $roles = [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN];
            // ...

            return new WebserviceUser($username, $password, $salt, $roles);
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
        );
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof WebserviceUser) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user))
            );
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return WebserviceUser::class === $class;
    }
}
```

**And modify the security.yml:**

```
security:
    access_denied_url:  /login
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
        AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser: md5

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [fos_userbundle, webservice]

        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

        webservice:
            id: app.webservice_user_provider

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            fr3d_ldap:  ~
            form_login:
                provider:   fos_userbundle
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login
            anonymous:    true
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern: ^/login$
            security: false
```

**Of course I also modified the services.yml to add the service app.webservice_user_provider:**
    services:
        app.form.group:
            class: AppBundle\Form\GroupFormType
            tags:
                - { name: form.type, alias: app_group_registration }

```
    app.form.user:
        class: AppBundle\Form\ProfileFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_profile }

    app.webservice_user_provider:
        class: AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUserProvider
```

This being done, the behavior is that the system allows access for the users of the fos_user provider, but not for the users of my custom provider. What is failing?

This it the log:

[2017-02-16 11:37:08] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_security_check". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\Controller\SecurityController::checkAction","_route":"fos_user_security_check"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/login_check"} []

```
[2017-02-16 11:37:08] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id_aspirante AS id_aspirante1, t0.correo AS correo2, t0.clave AS clave3, t0.status_cuenta AS status_cuenta4 FROM aspirantes2 t0 WHERE t0.correo = ? LIMIT 1 ["userFoo"] []

[2017-02-16 11:37:08] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id_aspirante AS id_aspirante1, t0.correo AS correo2, t0.clave AS clave3, t0.status_cuenta AS status_cuenta4 FROM aspirantes2 t0 WHERE t0.correo = ? LIMIT 1 ["userFoo"] []

[2017-02-16 11:37:08] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationServiceException(code: 0): The user provider must return a UserInterface object. at /home/userx/projects/myproj/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:94, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationServiceException(code: 0): The user provider must return a UserInterface object. at /home/userx/projects/myproj/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:86)"} []

[2017-02-16 11:37:08] security.DEBUG: Authentication failure, redirect triggered. {"failure_path":"/login"} []

[2017-02-16 11:37:08] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_security_login". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\SecurityController::loginAction","_route":"fos_user_security_login"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/login"} []

[2017-02-16 11:37:08] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []

[2017-02-16 11:37:08] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"c368df","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/_wdt/c368df"} []

[2017-02-16 11:37:08] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []

[2017-02-16 11:37:08] security.DEBUG: Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): Access Denied. at /home/userx/projects/myproj/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:70)"} []

[2017-02-16 11:37:08] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point. [] []

[2017-02-16 11:37:08] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_security_login". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\SecurityController::loginAction","_route":"fos_user_security_login"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/login"} []

[2017-02-16 11:37:08] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation I was able to understand the logic of authentication methods and I found it more convenient and easy to use for my project an authentication provider from a database. Really is a very simple solution that is documented in: [How to Load Security Users from the Database (the Entity Provider)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html)

In my case for being using FOSUserBundle there are two considerations:

1. They must exist two methods of authentication: the one provided by FOSUserBundle and the one provided by MyBundle.
2. The authentication process should attempt to authenticate the user in both methods.

For this, apart from the recommendations given in [How to Load Security Users from the Database (the Entity Provider)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html), you must modify some sections of security.yml so that they look like this::

```
encoders:
    // The database method of FOSUserBundle
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:
        algorithm: sha512
    // The data base method of mine
    MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity: 
        //This values depends on how the keys were encrypted in the database
        algorithm: md5
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations: 0

providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [fos_userbundle, aspirante_db]

    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    myentity_db:
        entity: { class: MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity, property: username }

firewalls:
    main:                                                                                                                              
        pattern:    ^/
        fr3d_ldap:  ~
        form_login:
            provider:   chain_provider //This is the important change
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login
        anonymous:    true
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        pattern: ^/login$
        security: false
```

That is all. I hope that in the future someone can take advantage of this post. Many thanks to madshvero for his guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating a [custom provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html) which checks for the user in both tables, and returns the user it finds.

Then you can update `app/config/security.yml` to use your provider instead of the one provided by FOSUserBundle:

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: the.id.of.your.provider
```

Comment: Hi madshvero, thanks for responding so quickly. I really do not want to use my provider instead of FOSUser, I want the user to look first at the FOSUser provider and if he is not looking for it in mine.

Comment: Is it an option to have your provider extend the FOSUserBundle provider, and first checking whether `parent::loadUserByUsername` throws an exception, and if so using your own logic for the other table? You could also in your provider use the [user manager](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php) that is used in the [provider in the FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Security/UserProvider.php) to look the users up